# Sources that all future souls were at Mount Sinai?

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul, har-sinai

What are the sources for the common understanding that all future souls were at Mount Sinai?

I saw the Chasam Sofer bring the gemarra in Shevuos ([39a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.39a.9)), but that's talking about parshas Nitzavim.

A quick sefaria search for the verse he brings does bring two Midrash Tanchumas ([Yisro #11](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Yitro.11.1), [Pekudei #3](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Pekudei.3.4)). Are these the only sources?

Comment: Pretty sure the Gemara in Shavuos is the source. Perhaps the better question to ask is why the Gemara interprets passuk, which clearly refers to the second covenant, as referring to Har Sinai. And it clearly does: אין לי אלא אותן העומדים על הר סיני.

Comment: Please rewrite the question, If you already know the answer and it's pre-Talmudic.

Comment: There are two approaches, as I remember - 1. that there were 600K persons standing on Mt Sinai, each one representing a soul, and all the following are reincarnations of those (unclear what's with women, kids, elderly - what souls were they) 2. That all the 600k souls were presented spiritually (G-d brought them with Him) and were later used populating living Jews.

Comment: Ignore the second part of my previous comment. That question’s been [asked already](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93665/).

Comment: @AlBerko I explicitly asked if there were other sources...what more do you want

Comment: @DonielF where in Shevuos is it talking about who was at Mount Sinai?

Comment: @robev Read the quote again: אין לי אלא אותן **העומדים על הר סיני**, implying that איננו are those who aren’t on Har Sinai.

Comment: @DonielF it's saying who was at arvos Moav....not only those who were at Sinai but all future generations. Who says future generations were at sinai

Comment: @robev By your reading, future generations aren’t included in the covenant in Nitzavim, either. How do you understand the continuation of the Gemara, קימו מה שקבלו כבר? They didn’t accept it previously if they weren’t included in that covenant. Rather איננו must mean all who weren’t yet alive. (Maharsha seems to understand the Gemara in this fashion FWIW.)

Comment: Strongly recommend you read the introduction to the commentary of Heichal HaBracha on  Chumash cited here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93677/7303   It addresses all these issues.